# How can I create a new STATIC Product attribute in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes

How can I create a new STATIC Product attribute in Magento 2?

We use barcode as a unique identifier (same as SKU) and are considering adding this - same as sku - as a STATIC attribute directly to product entity table

Why? We think this is faster during lookups ...

But we are not sure where/how this could unexpected problems

In short: How can I create a new STATIC Product attribute in Magento 2? And will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use custom static attributes in your project, you have to do 2 things in your install/upgrade scripts.

1. You need to add a column to the main entity table, with the correct column definition. There is not method to do this in 1 go.
2. Install your attribute using the `addAttribute()` method, and define your attribute as `static`.

Refer to the install scripts of `Mage_Catalog` to better understand how things work in this case.

```
$installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('catalog/product')}` ADD `has_options` SMALLINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
");

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'has_options', array(
    'type' => 'static',
    'visible'=>false,
    'default' => false
));
```